# Special Volumes in One Piece

Tags: one-piece, merchandise

I am an avid One Piece manga collector. Recently, I came across a volume named "Volume Zoro". It got me thinking if there are other Volumes I'm missing out. The volumes I currently own:

- Regular Volumes
- Volume 0
- Volume 1000
- Volume 777
- Volume 333
- 5 databooks
- Volume Zoro

  [image]

Comment: Can you provide some details about this? It is the first time i hear about it, is it some extra side story or an aggregation about zoro trivia?

Comment: @Proxy I don't have it with me as I live in the US I and had it mailed to my grandparents' place. Will post more details when I get my hands on it.

Comment: Volume Zoro is a separate (supplementary) volume attached to the May 2018 edition of Saikyo Jump comics. It's not a "stand-alone" volume. I'll post an answer if I get more details.